# How to show alert based on user input

Tags: javascript

```
var teams=[
  {key:1, label:"Faizel", type:1},
  {key:15, label:"Phumzi", type:1},
  {key:2, label:"Julian", type:2},
  {key:3, label:"Rydel", type:1},
  {key:14, label:"Srdjan", type:2},
  {key:5, label:"Doi", type:1},
  {key:6, label:"Brandon", type:2},
  {key:7, label:"Jose", type:1},
  {key:8, label:"Lesley", type:1},
  {key:9, label:"Robin", type:1},
  {key:10, label:"Bigshow", type:2},
  {key:11, label:"Template", type:1},
  {key:12, label:"Slab View", type:1},
  {key:13, label:"Dulla", type:1},
  {key:16, label:"Nelson", type:1},
];
```

I want to show the alert based on key that user input in text field (example) if user input 14 in text field the alert should say "Srdjan"

Comment: Use `alert` to show an alert, otherwise it is just a matter go going through the array looking for matches.

Comment: Where is your input and event handler?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: I have no idea how to do it  I have created simple input field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array#find`. Enter the `key` into `input` and hit `click` button.

```js
var teams = [{key:1,label:"Faizel",type:1},{key:15,label:"Phumzi",type:1},{key:2,label:"Julian",type:2},{key:3,label:"Rydel",type:1},{key:14,label:"Srdjan",type:2},{key:5,label:"Doi",type:1},{key:6,label:"Brandon",type:2},{key:7,label:"Jose",type:1},{key:8,label:"Lesley",type:1},{key:9,label:"Robin",type:1},{key:10,label:"Bigshow",type:2},{key:11,label:"Template",type:1},{key:12,label:"Slab View",type:1},{key:13,label:"Dulla",type:1},{key:16,label:"Nelson",type:1}],
    input = document.getElementById('inp');

function func(){
  var prop = teams.find(v => v.key == inp.value).label;
  console.log(prop);
}
```

```html
<input id='inp'>
<button onclick='func()'>click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks You made my day

Answer (score 0):

```js
var teams=[
  {key:1, label:"Faizel", type:1},
  {key:15, label:"Phumzi", type:1},
  {key:2, label:"Julian", type:2},
  {key:3, label:"Rydel", type:1},
  {key:14, label:"Srdjan", type:2},
  {key:5, label:"Doi", type:1},
  {key:6, label:"Brandon", type:2},
  {key:7, label:"Jose", type:1},
  {key:8, label:"Lesley", type:1},
  {key:9, label:"Robin", type:1},
  {key:10, label:"Bigshow", type:2},
  {key:11, label:"Template", type:1},
  {key:12, label:"Slab View", type:1},
  {key:13, label:"Dulla", type:1},
  {key:16, label:"Nelson", type:1},
];

var key = 14;

alert(teams.find(function(item){
  return item.key === key
}).label);
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter number and hit check

```js
var teams=[
{key:1, label:"Faizel", type:1},
{key:15, label:"Phumzi", type:1},
{key:2, label:"Julian", type:2},
{key:3, label:"Rydel", type:1},
{key:14, label:"Srdjan", type:2},
{key:5, label:"Doi", type:1},
{key:6, label:"Brandon", type:2},
{key:7, label:"Jose", type:1},
{key:8, label:"Lesley", type:1},
{key:9, label:"Robin", type:1},
{key:10, label:"Bigshow", type:2},
{key:11, label:"Template", type:1},
{key:12, label:"Slab View", type:1},
{key:13, label:"Dulla", type:1},
{key:16, label:"Nelson", type:1},
];
function check(){
var val=document.getElementById('inputT').value;
if(val!=""){

for(var i=0;i<teams.length;i++){
  if(teams[i].key==val){
          alert(teams[i].label)
        }
}
}
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputT">
<button onclick="check()">
check
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```js
var teams = [
  {key:1, label:"Faizel", type:1},
  {key:15, label:"Phumzi", type:1},
  {key:2, label:"Julian", type:2},
  {key:3, label:"Rydel", type:1},
  {key:14, label:"Srdjan", type:2},
  {key:5, label:"Doi", type:1},
  {key:6, label:"Brandon", type:2},
  {key:7, label:"Jose", type:1},
  {key:8, label:"Lesley", type:1},
  {key:9, label:"Robin", type:1},
  {key:10, label:"Bigshow", type:2},
  {key:11, label:"Template", type:1},
  {key:12, label:"Slab View", type:1},
  {key:13, label:"Dulla", type:1},
  {key:16, label:"Nelson", type:1},
];

document.getElementById('displayAlert').addEventListener("click", function() {
  var inputVal = document.getElementById('team').value;
  var selectedTeam = teams.find(function(value) {
    return value.key === parseInt(inputVal);
  });
  alert(selectedTeam.label);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="team">
<button id="displayAlert">Display Alert</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4).

With it, it comes easy to find objects based on attributes:

```
// get the input with jquery
var value = $('#myinput').val();

var resultObject = _.find(teams, function(obj) {
    return obj.key === parseInt(value);
});

alert(resultObject.label);
```

Comment: No, I don't suggest using lodash.